# Use Symfony entities and doctrine mapping without database

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

We are migrating our project from custom CMS to Symfony 5.1. Instead of Database, we are using REST API. Currently we are using Entities without connecting them to any database (with no `@ORM` annotation or configuration file), and we put all REST logic inside a Repository folder

Currently, if we save our entity in SESSION

```
$example = new Example();
$request->getSession()->set('example', $example);
```

On every next request, we will get error:

```
Class "App\Entity\Example" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

Of course, this could be fixed if we put correct `@ORM` annotations, but then it requires a database.

Can this be fixed, and if it's not possible, what would be proper architecture for this scenario?

Comment: If you are not using some kind of database, logically doctrine is not what you need. Just create your own entity classes and repository classes. And it's generally not that great or necessary to store whole objects in the session, but if you do, make you they are serializable.

Comment: Class "App\Entity\Example" is not a valid entity or mapped super class, Doctrine somewhere wants to map that entity.

Comment: Try commenting out the two doctrine classes in config/bundles.php.  Might also need to remove the two doctrine config/packages files.

Answer (score 0):

Let doctrine be the tool to manage the data. In fact that there is no database, you will need something similar to let doctrine manage the data of the REST API.

Take a look at this bundle:
https://github.com/CircleOfNice/DoctrineRestDriver

Edit:
In addition to one of the comments, the DoctrineRestDriver is not maintained anymore. In fact, the bundle does not support Symfony 5.x.
To use the functionality of DoctrineRestDriver you could downgrade your symfony to the supported 4.x.
Your architectur to use doctrine to manage your rest-api can be solved by using the DoctrineRestDriver package.

If you don’t want to downgrade your symfony, you will have to implement your own „data-manager-solution“, to use the api as your database.

But I think the architectural problem with the rest api doesn’t relate directly to your current error. We need more code to understand, where your specific mapped super class error is from (repository, entity).

Comment: That bundle is great, but that bundle is not maintained anymore, and don't support Symfony 5.1